# Spring Quartz Dynamically adding Jobs

Tags: spring, quartz-scheduler, spring-scheduled

I am trying to add a job to the scheduler dynamically by

```
schedulerFactoryBean.getScheduler().scheduleJob(cronTrigger);
```

But this is giving an error

```
Caused by: org.quartz.JobPersistenceException: The job (JOB_GROUP.JOB_NAME) referenced by the trigger does not exist.
    at org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore.storeTrigger(RAMJobStore.java:422)
    at org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler.scheduleJob(QuartzScheduler.java:932)
    at org.quartz.impl.StdScheduler.scheduleJob(StdScheduler.java:258)
    at com.abc.RescheduleJob.rescheduleJobs(RescheduleJob.java:32)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.util.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:269)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean$MethodInvokingJob.executeInternal(MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean.java:257)
```

Please help.

Comment: share your code how you are trying to add.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The job referenced](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21120211/the-job-referenced)